# I am getting following error "appium &" commnad not found on MAC

Tags: ios, macos, appium

I have configured appium and node using following steps:

```
brew install node 
brew link node 
npm install -g appium@1.4.11
npm install wd
```

Now when I execute `appium &`,it says command not found. Please help me in starting the appium server.

Please help me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

```
ln -fs /Users/<your user name>/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js /usr/local/bin/appium
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/appium
```

This is surely gonna help!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me -

```
brew install node # "or second line if npm is installed"
npm i -g npm
npm install -g appium
npm install wd
```

Answer (score 0):

> brew install node
>
> npm install -g appium
>
> npm install wd
>
> appium &

use this

sudo npm cache clean -f

Answer (score 0):

Follow this doc- it contains step by step instructions [Appium setup on mac](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0RYNvExsRQJeHB6Zy1GeVBLcmM/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please ensure you have installed appium successfully, the installation print out should end with some thing like └── appium@1.5.3

Secondly, make sure */usr/local/bin* is in your PATH variable, check by

```
echo $PATH
```

If above were configured correctly but error still persisted, it's likely that appium script does not exist in your */usr/local/bin* directory, try this:

```
ln -fs /Users/<your user name>/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js /usr/local/bin/appium
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/appium
```